SSH connection problem BBB(Beagle Bone Black) on WSL2 Ubuntu 24.04
As the title suggests, I tried to establish an SSH connection to my BeagleBone Black device from the Ubuntu 24.04 operating system that I'm using with WSL2 on my Windows 11 computer, and I encountered some issues. I'll describe the process step by step for your assistance.

First, I bound the device defined as a storage device using the following command:
usbipd bind --busid 2-3


Then, I connected it using the following command:
usbipd attach --wsl --busid 2-3


After these commands, when I ran the following command on the Ubuntu side:
sudo lshw -class network

I saw that a new network device was added.
I activated this new network device with:
sudo ip link set dev eth1 up

And I assigned an IP address with:
sudo ip addr add 192.168.7.1/24 dev eth1

but I couldn't get a response when I pinged it.

Note: I have installed mkudevrule.sh.

Remember that 192.168.7.1 will be YOUR IP address. The BBB might be .2 or similar. You can try running nmap to see if it can find anything on that subnet, if it's installed: sudo nmap -v -sT -O 192.168.7.0/24
Showing the output from ip addr may also be helpful.
